# Aggregate Query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB. I have a requirement to get the latest updated product for particular date from a array of products.
    Below is the JSON object of my requirement.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("10001"),
    "product": [{
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 1,
        "updatedDate": "14-03-2017"
    }, {
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 2,
        "updatedDate": "14-03-2017"
    }, {
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 1,
        "updatedDate": "15-03-2017"
    }, {
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 2,
        "updatedDate": "15-03-2017"
    }, {
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 3,
        "updatedDate": "15-03-2017"
    }, {
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 4,
        "updatedDate": "15-03-2017"
    }]
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("10002"),
    "product": [{
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 1,
        "updatedDate": "14-03-2017"
    }, {
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 2,
        "updatedDate": "14-03-2017"
    }, {
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 1,
        "updatedDate": "15-03-2017"
    }, {
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 2,
        "updatedDate": "15-03-2017"
    }, {
        "image": "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name": "product",
        "version": 3,
        "updatedDate": "15-03-2017"
    }]
},
}
```

I need a query - which will retrieve a product with 14-03-2017 with latest version.

Expected Result is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("10001"),
"product" : [
    {"image" : "./../../../prod1.html","name" : "product","version" : 4,"updatedDate":"15-03-2017"} 
]},
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("10002"),
"product" : [
    {"image" : "./../../../prod1.html","name" : "product","version" : 3,"updatedDate":"15-03-2017"} 
]}
```

It would be highly appreciate some one can help me with the aggregate function to get the expected outcome.

Comment: Need to fetch the product with latest date and latest version in that date(Date will contain with multiple versions)

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregate command,

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$product"
}, {
    $sort: {
        "product.updatedDate": 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        product: {
            $last: "$product"
        }
    }
}])
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("10002"),
    "product" : {
        "image" : "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name" : "product",
        "version" : 3,
        "updatedDate" : "15-03-2017"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("10001"),
    "product" : {
        "image" : "./../../../prod1.html",
        "name" : "product",
        "version" : 4,
        "updatedDate" : "15-03-2017"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Friend, Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. Thanks for your immediate respond.